# I Could not print an output in PHP using (HP Deskjet F380) in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, php

I could not give print to HP Deskjet F380 printer in PHP coding.

I tried this

```
require_once(PrintIPP.php);
$ipp = new PrintIPP();
$ipp->setHost("localhost");
$ipp->setPrinterURI("/printers/epson");
$ipp->setData("./filename.pdf"); // Path to file.
$ipp->printJob();
?>
```

shoud I do any changes in php.ini file ? and how ?,  please help me as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance
Ajmal

Comment: Is the user running your web server process a member of whatever group gets access to your printers?

Answer (score 2):

`/printers/epson` is the example URI from the documentation.  You need to look at your CUPS configuration and determine the correct name for your HP Deskjet.  Then you would use `/printers/DeskJet` (or whatever the printer name is)